# How can I use Mock to test my controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I have a controller:

```
public class SelectController : Controller {
    private readonly IChartService _chartService;
    private readonly IProductService _productService;
    private readonly IStoreService _storeService;

    public SelectController ( IChartService chartService,
                              IProductService productService,
                              IStoreService storeService ) {
        _chartService = chartService;
        _productService = productService;
        _storeService = storeService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route( "stores" )]
    public Task<IEnumerable<IStore>> GetStoresInfo ( string encryptedUserId ) {
        return _storeService.GetStoresInfo( EncryptionProvider.Decrypt( encryptedUserId ) );
    }
}
```

I am trying to test `GetStoresInfo` using Moq. This is all I have so far:

```
[Fact]
public class Controller_Returns_List_Of_Stores()
{
    //Arrange
    var mockStoreService = new Mock<IStoreService>();
    var mockChartService = new Mock<IChartService>();
    var mockProductService = new Mock<IProductService>();



    var controller = new SelectController(mockChartService, mockProductService, mockStoreService);

    //Act
    //Assert
}
```

The new `SelectController` wont accept the 3 objects I am passing in due to being unable to convert from `InService` to `InService`. Am I meant to be doing some more setup? Or is it something to do with the return type being a Task?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `.Object` on the mocks to pass the mocked objects.

```
 var controller = new SelectController(
     mockChartService.Object, 
     mockProductService.Object, 
     mockStoreService.Object
);
```

You also need to setup the mock object's behavior so that they function as expected when invoked.

```
IEnumerable<IStore> fakeData = new List<IStore>();

mockStoreService
    .Setup(_ => _.GetStoresInfo(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<IStore>>(fakeData));
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use the mocking framework.